# mysql query join group_concat

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following query,

```
 SELECT 
     p.id AS parent, GROUP_CONCAT( c.id ) AS children
 FROM 
     rev_r_clients AS p
 JOIN 
     rev_r_clients AS c ON c.parent_client_id = p.id
 GROUP BY 
     p.id
```

It get the `id` as parent and the children of the parent. After that I send the mapping `id` to array using the following function,

```
$parents = Array();

while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $parents[$row['parent']] = explode(',',$row['children']);
}
```

I need it to get a `username` from another table (`rev_users`) as well, how could this be done?

Comment: add to the join rev_users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to achieve this with two queries (or alternatively one MySQL transaction using a subquery) then you could concat like this:

```
SELECT 
    p.id AS parent_id, p_u.name, GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(c.id, '-', c_u.name) ) AS children
FROM 
    rev_r_clients AS p
JOIN 
    rev_r_clients AS c ON c.parent_client_id = p.id
JOIN 
    rev_users c_u ON c_u.id= c.id
JOIN 
    rev_users p_u ON p.id = p_u.id
GROUP BY 
    p.id
```

Be careful doing this though.  There are limits on how big a GROUP_CONCAT can get.  See the documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

And your code would look like

```
$parents = Array();
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
  $children = explode(',',$row['children']);
  foreach($children as $child){
    $child_info = explode('-', $child);
    if(!isset($parents[$row['parent_id']])){
      $parents[$row['parent']] = array(
        'id' => $row['parent'],
        'name' => $row['name'],
        'children' => array()
      )
    }
    $parents[$row['parent']]['children'][] = array(
      'id' => $child_info[0],
      'name' => $child_info[1]
    );
  }
}
```

Lastly be careful to use a separator in your CONCAT function that you know will not be in the name.

Comment: that was very helpful , thank you but now how could i print childs and names for a parent id?
in the old example i could do that with a recursive function like that

function subtree($id, $parents) { 
    echo ' <tr><td> <b>Client No.:</b> </td><td><a href="index.php?pg=infoid"> ';echo $id;echo ' </a></td></tr> ';
if (isset($parents[$id]))
    foreach ($parents[$id] as $child) 
    {
     subtree($child, $parents);
    }
    }

Comment: Not sure what the problem is? Is the query not returning the data you need? Or are you wondering how to output this new data structure?

Comment: I edited my answer - now you have a consistent structure - your recursive function will look like `function subtree($id, $parents){ echo $parents[$id]['id']; if(isset($parents[$id]['children'])){subtree($id, $parents):}}`.  There are probably cleaner ways to do this but I am simply trying to help you arrive at the end of the path you started down.

Comment: am getting this error : mysql join concatbool(false) Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in

Comment: Looks like there is a mysql error - possibly due to some bad data.  Without having access to your DB I can't really help you.  Maybe wrap the concat function in an if `IF(//do sanity checks on data, CONCAT, '')`?

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'u.name' in 'field list'

Comment: Ahh - Edited query to fix that.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'u.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: You should consider doing away with group concat and just dealing with extra records in results set.  This would eliminat need for all the explodes when trying to put data into PHP array.